# php get all command line arguments as associative array

Tags: php

Is it possible to get all php command line arguments as an associative array in the format of:

```
argument --option1 --option2 argument2 --option1
```

would be output as

```
'arguments' => array(
    'argument' => array(
        'option1', 'option2'  
     ),
     'argument2' => array(
         'option1'
     )
)
```

but the solution should be generic

Comment: Have you tried getopt()?
I think you'll reach that goal with it. (With some work however) See http://www.php.net/getopt

Comment: what would the command line look like in the above ?? both "argument" and "option" in the above on the php command line are just arguments.

Comment: That's not quite how command line flags work.  You don't pass `arguments` and `options` like that.  It's usually `command --option1 --option2=value -option3 value`.

Comment: more usually a list of arguments the script then assigns as required.

Comment: few apps use this convetion, and even then the order is `--option1 --option2 argument --option1 argument2`